# Reading only a single column from data frame

Tags: python

I have a dataframe. It has seven columns. I will take first column as index. I want to read only one column from that dataframe. I know if I want to read more than one, I can use `usecols` arguments. But for only single column, how I can read it? I can do it using the following two lines of code. But is it possible to read it with a single line of code?

```
sensex=pd.read_csv("sensex.csv",index_col="Date")
sensex_close=sensex.loc[:,["Close"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following code will solve your purpose

```
sensex_close = pd.read_csv('sensex.csv',index_col="Date")[["Close"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sensex=pd.read_csv("sensex.csv",index_col="Date", usecols=["Close"])
```

Comment: I use it. It results in following error. ValueError: Index Date invalid